# Wake on LAN Powershell script not working

Tags: .net, shell, powershell, networking, wake-on-lan

I've been trying to wake a computer on LAN from a shutdown state. The computer that is sending the WOL request is a windows 10 machine and the machine i'm trying to wake is a Windows 10 machine. 
I've tried a few scripts that I've found on the internet most of the scripts use the .net class [UdpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)

I've made sure the computer I'm trying to wake has wake on LAN enabled on both the BIOS and the NIC.

The network subnet I'm on is a 255.255.0.0 subnet.
The IP adress is dynamic and is assigned via a DHCP server.

The Script I'm using is:

[WakeUp-Machines – A PowerShell script for Wake On LAN](http://blogs.technet.com/b/matthts/archive/2012/06/02/wakeup-machines-a-powershell-script-for-wake-on-lan.aspx)

So far it's not waking from LAN, Any advice on where I might be going wrong or A script which is sure to work...

Cheers,

A Walter

Comment: Can you wake up the computer with other utilities like MagicPacket? Not sure if this matters for the script but are you in the same subnet for your testing? Devices might be blocking the broadcast.

Comment: Run the box you want to wake on lan and install a packet capture, like wireshark.  Even though it's running, send a WOL request... does it show up in the pcap?  It's possible a network device between you is dropping the packet (quite common actually)

Comment: Hmm. Interesting, I will try this. Also we are on the same sub-net and both computers can ping each other.

Comment: By using wire shark, I can determine that the machine is receiving the packets from the power shell script. So the problem is with the machine not waking when it receives the magic packets .

Answer (score 2):

The script is working. The problem was not with the script but with the computer receiving the magic packet. The problem was being caused by windows *Fast Startup* and it required me to turn this feature off.

The article below outlines all the settings needed to enable wake on LAN.

**[How to Enable Wake-on-LAN in Windows 10](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/enable-wake-on-lan-windows-10/)**

Thanks to *Colyn1337* for their useful comment which lead me to solving my own problem.

**Comment**

> Run the box you want to wake on lan and install a packet capture, like wireshark. Even though it's running, send a WOL request... does it show up in the pcap? It's possible a network device between you is dropping the packet (quite common actually) – Colyn1337